# Query string using LINQ

Tags: c#, string, linq

For parsing SDP information from an RTSP, currently I use default c# string functions (like loop the string line by line) and foreach/switch methods. Default SDP information comes from a device in this form:

```
v=0
o=mhandley 2890844526 2890842807 IN IP4 126.16.64.4
s=SDP Seminar
i=A Seminar on the session description protocol
u=http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/M.Handley/sdp.03.ps
e=mjh@isi.edu (Mark Handley)
c=IN IP4 224.2.17.12/127
t=2873397496 2873404696
a=recvonly
m=audio 3456 RTP/AVP 0
m=video 2232 RTP/AVP 31
m=whiteboard 32416 UDP WB
a=orient:portrait
```

Im wondering is this string is query-able using LINQ or something instead of foreaching each line, switching the first character and then storing the rest as a value, because this method is very sensitive to malfunction and error (like when 2 attributes/params are on 1 line or the first character isn't accidentally the right one (e.g. with a space before)). Before I begin to cover every damn exception than can occur, I'm wondering if there's a technique to query a string for values/keys using LINQ.

Comment: What expected result you want to store?

Comment: You have three items for `m` key. How you suppose to handle that?

Comment: @CuongLe For the unique keys like v,o,s, I have specific variables. For * keys like m, as you see in the example above, I'd like to use lists. There are another type of key/value not in this example: Attributes. They are written as following:
'a=fmpt:RTP/96'
So I'd like to query for attributes (a's), then query for the key (string before :) and values (string after :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var query = text.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(line => line.Split('='))
                .GroupBy(x => x[0], x => x[1])
                .Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Values = g.ToList() });
```

This will return entries grouped by key with values as list.

Or this way (if Linq Lookup is OK for you):

```
var lookup = text.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 .Select(line => line.Split('='))
                 .ToLookup(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

Usage:

```
foreach (var value in lookup["m"])
    // use value
```

Comment: This! A hundred-times! Thank you very much for this understandable example.

Answer (score 1):

you undoubtedly *can* do it with linq, but a simple loop (perhaps using `StringReader` to get the lines) checking `line.Length != 0` then looking and `line[0]` and `line.Substring(1)` is probably more appropriate:

```
static void Process(string input)
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader(input))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if(line.Length == 0) continue;

            char first = line[0];
            string rest = line.Substring(1);
            // ... process this line
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the case when 2 key/value pairs occur on one line? ReadLine would be useless in this case.

Comment: @user1450661 then you need to define what the correct behavior is in that case (which you have not yet done)... it sounds to me like that is an error scenario, and the user **should not expect** it to work.